# How can I animate falling snowflakes in JS?

Tags: javascript, animation

For a school project I need to create a Christmas card using JavaScript and I'm having trouble getting my snowflake to be created at different times and with a different x-value than the rest of the other snowflakes.

Right now, I have how the snowflake should look while its falling but I need some help generating the rest of the snow.

Here's the code for when it falls:

```
sy++;
if(sy <= 400) {
    snowy = sy;
} else {
    sy = 0;
}

sx++;
if(sx < 400) {
    snowx1 = sx;
    snowx2 = sx + 1;
} else {
    sx = 0;
}

ellipse(random(snowx1, snowx2), snowy, 10, 10);
```

How do I get that specific animation generated at different x-values without changing the random() part?

Answer (score 4):

```js
var snow_intensity = 50; // smaller number = more snowflakes;

function Snowflake(){
  var snowflake = this;
  snowflake.x = (Math.random() * $(document).width());
  snowflake.size = (Math.random() * 35) + 10;
  snowflake.opacity = Math.random();
  snowflake.body = $("<em class='snowflake'>*</em>");
  snowflake.body.css({'font-size': this.size + 'px', 'left': this.x +'px', opacity: this.opacity });
  snowflake.fall = function(){
    var that = this;
    var $snowflake = this.body;
    var swing_direction = 1;
    var swing_wave = Math.random() * 100;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
      $snowflake.css({left: that.x + (swing_direction * swing_wave)});
      swing_direction = - swing_direction;
    }, 1000);
    var speed = (Math.random() * 3000) + 3000;
    $snowflake.animate({top: '100vh'}, speed, function(){
      clearInterval(interval);
      $snowflake.remove();
    });    
  }
  $('body').append(snowflake.body);
  snowflake.fall();
}

var snow = window.setInterval(function () {
   new Snowflake();
}, snow_intensity);

document.onkeypress = function () {
  window.clearInterval(snow);
};
```

```css
body {background: CornflowerBlue;overflow:hidden;}
h1 {
  color:LightSkyBlue;
  text-align:center;
  opacity:.2;
}
.snowflake{
  position:absolute;
  top:-40px;
  transition: left 5s;
  opacity:1;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
  animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>HAPPY NEW YEAR</h1>
```

Comment: This is amazing! How do I make it so it snows inside a div with ID? I tried changed the "body" to the div ID but it didn't work...